# Linking Cocoa headers to ruby C extension

Tags: objective-c, c, ruby, makefile, ruby-c-extension

I am working on a C extension for ruby, but I need to include headers from the `IOBluetooth` framework, specifically:

```
#import <IOBluetooth/objc/IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry.h>
#import <IOBluetooth/IOBluetoothUserLib.h>
```

Everything compiles fine, but at runtime, the extension errors:

```
path/to/file.rb:1:in `require_relative': dlopen(/path/to/extension.bundle, 9):
Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry (LoadError)
```

I am fairly sure this has something to do with the framework not being included in the linking process, but I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

`extconf.rb`:

```
# Loads mkmf which is used to make makefiles for Ruby extensions
require 'mkmf'

# Give it a name
extension_name = 'bluetooth'

dir_config(extension_name)

create_makefile(extension_name, 'bluetooth')
```

**Generated MakeFile:** http://paste.wilhall.com/25

**UPDATE:**
I modified the Makefile so that the library statically links; still experiencing the same error, but this time when linking.

Oddly, `have_header` in my `extconf.rb` file finds these header files fine.

**UPDATE:**
I have pulled the following from the system log files:

```
Process:         ruby [951]
Path:            /usr/local/bin/ruby
Identifier:      ruby
Version:         0
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [468]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-10-17 14:06:57.425 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.1 (12B19)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
```

If I remember correctly, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)` is often related to a GC issue? Will look into it and post results

Comment: this is an awesome question +1

Answer (score 1):

This seems too simple, so I might be off, but it looks right from what you've posted. It looks like the problem isn't the headers, but that you aren't linking the IOBluetooth framework itself. Are you specifying anything like `-framework IOBluetooth` anywhere?

Comment: I apologize, the MakeFile I posted is a freshly generated one. I edited it to include `IOBluetooth` as a framework. See the last part of the question for the new part of the error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you included

```
-framework Foundation System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/IOBluetooth
```

In your makeFile. Be sure you have the framework in the right directory.
But if you can compile it, link it, your IOBluetooth seems now in your binary.

By the way you are trying to access a pointer at address 0x02, this is what creating the crash. I'm not sure it's related to IOBluetooth anymore